# iOS 5 segue initialize more than one property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

i did segue with one property it works but the second property causes error "no known instance method for selector..."

how many variables one can initialize when segueing?

`[segue.destinationViewController  setID:1 setName:@"name"];`

with either of the setters it works but no more than one. any idea why? and how to set more than property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of the destinationViewController and edit that.

```
UIViewController *nextController = [segue destinationViewControler];

[nextController setID:1];
[nextController setName:@"name"];
```

If you are working with a custom class you will need to do it slightly differently:

```
YourClass *nextController = (YourClass *)[segue destinationViewController];

[nextController setID:1];
[nextController setName:@"name"];
```

Sorry if there are any typos. I know this works because I have used it in multiple applications.

Answer (score 2):

Override the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in the originating view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
  controller.ID = 1;
  controller.name = @"name";
}
```